# Include source folder to classpath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

Eclipse complains if I add source folder as a class folder in Java Build Path / Library.

I need this for GWT that requires sources to be in the classpath. One solution is to manually add source folders of all projects to classpath of the launch configuration, but this is not suitable for me because of specific reasons.

Another solution would be to tell Eclipse to copy all `*.java` files to `bin` folder (as it does for other resources), but I can't achieve this too.

Comment: Complaint: How to configure eclipse project so that if I run it, it will contain not only bin folder, but also src folder in it's runtime classpath. In the launch configuration I don't want to manually edit the classpath, because the project depends on many other projects (using IvyDE) and I don't want to manually add the source folder of every dependant project to the launch configuration.

Comment: Laf, GWT needs java files in the classpath.

Comment: Oups, I had missed that part somehow, deleted my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the GWT plug-in by Google (http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html). Although I have not used it, a collegue of mine did, and I am reasonably sure it handles this kind of java code in the classpath issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution - to add Ant builder to all projects pointing to the following ant file:

```
<project name="Copy Sources" basedir="." default="copy-src">
    <target name="copy-src">
        <copy todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

My .project files look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-project1</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
            <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
            <arguments>
                <dictionary>
                    <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
                    <value>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;launchConfiguration local=&quot;false&quot; path=&quot;/gwt-dev-support/Copy Sources.launch&quot;/&gt;</value>
                </dictionary>
                <dictionary>
                    <key>incclean</key>
                    <value>true</value>
                </dictionary>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```